# MediatorLiveData doesn't work in JUnit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, android-livedata

So I've tried using MediatorLiveData for the rather simple use-case of converting an ISO country code (e.g. "US") to a country calling code (e.g. "+1") through the use of libphonenumber. The resulting screen works fine, but seems to fail JUnit tests, even when InstantTaskExecutorRule is used.

Example minimal unit test (in Kotlin) that I believe should pass, but fails instead:

```
import android.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import android.arch.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test

class MediatorLiveData_metaTest {
    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Test
    fun mediatorLiveData_metaTest() {
        val sourceInt = MutableLiveData<Int>()
        val mediatedStr = MediatorLiveData<String>()

        mediatedStr.addSource(sourceInt) {
            mediatedStr.value = it.toString()
        }

        sourceInt.value = 123

        assertEquals("123", mediatedStr.value) // says mediatedStr.value is null
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to note that I tried similar UI-less tests on the Android OS too and still couldn't get them to pass, even when I changed the setValue to postValue and added Thread.sleep before the assertion.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Thanks to Reddit user [matejdro](https://www.reddit.com/user/matejdro); the answer was that like Schrödinger's proverbial cat, MediatorLiveData won't update itself unless observed, so I'd need a `mediatedStr.observeForever{}` to force it to update itself.

Comment: Thanks for the trick, it was really helpful. However, I don't get to understand why when using the observe(lifecycleOwner, observer) fun, with the test class being the lifecycleOwner, it is not triggered... it works fine for regular LiveData objects, but not for MediatorLiveData. I only got to make it work with the observeForever function as you proposed.

Comment: If you implement LifecycleOwner in your own class, you need to implement getLifecycle() and update the lifecycle's state as necessary. See this class that I sometimes use in my tests https://github.com/Spheniscine/kbindingsample/blob/master/kbinding/src/main/java/com/github/spheniscine/kbinding/ControllableLifecycleOwner.kt

Comment: Yeah I know, I observe other LiveData objects successfully in my tests, so the implementation and state are correct. It just doesn't work for MediatorLiveData. For them only the "observe forever" seems to work.

Comment: I have prefered to use observer that uses LifecycleOwner : https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/use-mediatorlivedata-to-query-and-merge-different-data-type/